# Jquery - How to replace a selected element's value and then submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

### The Problem:

Here is the task at hand:

1. We have have a form. This form has a hidden input field in it with the name and id of "page"
2. I have pagination links. When the form is submitted, the results are paginated. The links have the page numbers contained in their href attribute.
3. When a pagination link is clicked, I want to extract the page number from the pagination link. (this is stored in the pageNumber variable), and replace the hidden field's value in my form with this pageNumber, and then submit the form (without following through on the pagination link that was clicked).

Is this at all possible? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

(Note I am using rails, and this is contained in the application.js file:

```
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(event){        
  var ransack_form = $('form').clone();    // clone the form on page load.
                                           // form is passed into the function.
                                           // <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="4" class="pagy-page">
  $(document).on('click', 'a.page-link', {form: ransack_form}, function(event){  
    var pageNumber = $(this).attr("href");    
    var form = event.data.form;
                // The form has a hidden input element with id and name being: "gage"
                // we want to replace the hidden input's value with the pageNumber value
                // obtained from above. How can this be done?
    form('.pagy-page').val(pageNum);    
    form.submit();  
                // We want to prevent the pagination link from being clicked.
                // event.preventDefault() prevents this from happening 
                // but we also want the form to be submitted at the same time!
                // is there a way around this?                
       });
    });
```

### Updated Code:

1. Thanks to Barmar we are at the stage where we now have a fully edited form that we need to submit.
2. When the pagination URL link is clicked, we want the form to be submitted WHILE ALSO preventing the browser from following the URL link. For some reason, the form is not being submitted:

Here is the updated code:

```
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(event){        
  var ransack_form = $('form').clone();    // clone the form on page load.
                                           // form is passed into the function.
                                           // <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="4" class="pagy-page">
  $(document).on('click', 'a.page-link', {form: ransack_form}, function(event){  
    var pageNumber = $(this).attr("href");    
    var form = event.data.form;             
    form.find('.pagy-page').val(pageNumber);    
    form.submit();  
    event.preventDefault();
                // We want to prevent the pagination link from being clicked.
                // event.preventDefault() prevents this from happening 
                // but we also want the form to be submitted at the same time!
                // How can we submit the form (and allow the page to be refreshed)
                // while at the same time preventing the url to be clicked.
       });
    });
```

### The Final Solution:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(event){        
  var ransack_form = $('form').clone();    // clone the form on page load.
                                           // form is passed into the function.
                                           // <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="4" class="pagy-page">
  $(document).on('click', 'a.page-link', {form: ransack_form}, function(event){  
    var pageNumber = $(this).attr("href");    
    var form = event.data.form;             
    form.find('.pagy-page').val(pageNumber);              
    form.appendTo($(this)).submit();    
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixing The Form Replacement Problem

`form` is a jQuery object, not a function, so `form('.pagy-page')` won't work. You need to call the `.find()` method:

```
form.find('.pagy-page').val(pageNum);
```

### Why Won't a Cloned Form be submitted?

You cannot submit a disconnected form. Try this:

```
form.appendTo($(this)).submit();
```

Comment: ok chrs. would you know how i can submit the form from an event handler when a link is clicked (while preventing the link from submitting)?

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` in the click handler.

Comment: Or `return false;` at the end. jQuery turns that into `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: thank you but for some reason, the form is not submitting. WOuld you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to clone the form? Does it work if you use `var ransack_form = $('form')`?

Comment: yes it works when i use `var ransack_form = $('form')`. The reason I want to clone the form is that I want the form as it stands when the page was uploaded to be submitted. If I use your suggestion, then the user might type in some new values in the form's fields - as those new values would get submitted as well - which is problematic when i'm trying to paginate because the pagination would not be applicable to those new search result terms. it seems so though the cloned form is not being submitted. any ideas?

Comment: ok I've found the solution - you can't clone forms without changing their ids and submitting them

Comment: I don't see how that other question is relevant. You're not inserting the cloned form into the DOM. And duplicate IDs are only a problem if you try to use the ID to select the element.

Comment: I suspect the real problem is that you can't submit a disconnected form. Try `form.appendTo(body).submit()`

Comment: Congratulations Barmar - you were right! It now works like a charm. Thanks for your help!